# select all checkboxes doesn't work on internet explorer 9

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, checkbox

i am trying to **check/uncheck** all checkboxes upon clicking on **select all/deselect all** checkbox as follows:

```
onclick="selectAll(document.getElementsByName('myForm:checkboxes'));"
```

and the JS function:

```
function selectAll(checkboxes)
        {       
                for(var i in checkboxes)
                checkboxes[i].checked = true;
        }

function deselectAll(checkboxes)
            {       
                    for(var i in checkboxes)
                    checkboxes[i].checked = false;
            }
```

and the HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="15" name="myForm:checkboxes" id="myForm:checkboxes3:_1">
```

this code works fine in firefox, but in internet explorer 9 it doesn't work.

Comment: maybe the : in the name is causing some issues?

Comment: Don't use `for (var i in ...)` for arrays. This form is used for objects only!

Comment: @Andreas, what to use instead ?

Comment: @Msaleh `for...` - Your code worked for me in IE9.

Comment: Try [`for (var i=0,len=checkboxes.length;i<len;i++){ // do stuff }`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for).

Comment: @Msaleh Press F12 to open your developer tools, switch to your Console tab, and see if there is any output or errors when you try to select or deselect checkboxes.

Comment: @Jonathan Sampson♦, i was getting no errors in console, the answer for david was correct.

Comment: @David Thomas, the iteration was the problem, it works fine now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Posting comment as answer:

A `for..in` loop, from the documentation at Mozilla Developer Network:

> A for...in loop iterates over the properties of an object in an arbitrary order

As your `checkboxes` are a nodeList, rather than an object, the `for` loop should be used instead.

So, instead of `for...in`, use:

```
for (var i=0,len=checkboxes.length;i<len;i++){
    // do stuff
}
```

References:

- [`for (){/*...*/}`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for).
- [`for..in` loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in).

Comment: Most importantly, the `for .. in` loop includes default properties on the object. In an array (or a nodeList), this includes things such as the `.length` property. Even regular objects can be caught out by this if your code adds properties to the object prototype. It is possible to use `for .. in` for all of these, but you need to add an `if(obj.hasOwnProperty(key))` condition immediately inside the loop. For safety, this should be done for *all* `for .. in` loops. See also: http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2011/01/04/exploring-javascript-for-in-loops/ and http://www.jshint.com/